# RTL - test expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name, value }) not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

Im using Material-Ui & Typescript.
I`m testing the 'onChange' input component and it does not working with value.

Form component wraps the input component and it holds the input state.

```
  const Form: React.FC = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({ name: '', email: '' });

    const { name, email } = state;

    const onChange = ({ target: { name, value }}:IOnChange) => setState({ ...state, [name]: value });

    const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
      e.preventDefault();

    };
    
    return (
      <Grid xs={12} container item component='form' onSubmit={onSubmit} noValidate>
        <Input
          label={'Name'}
          name='name'
          value={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          type='text'
        />
        <Input
          label={'Email'}
          name='email'
          value={email}
          onChange={onChange}
          type='email'
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  export default Form;
```

this is the Input component:

```
    const Input: React.FC<IProps> = ({ label, name, value, onChange, type }) => (
      <TextField
        label={label}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => onChange(e)}
        type={type}
        variant="outlined"
        inputProps={{
          "data-testid": `input-${name}`,
        }}
      />
    );

    interface IProps {
      label: string
      name: string
      value: string
      onChange: (e:React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & { target: { name: string, value: string }}) => void
      type: string
    };

    export default Input;
```

And this is my test:

```
 import { cleanup, fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react";

    const props = { label: 'label', name: 'name', value: '', onChange: jest.fn(), type:'text' };

    const { name, onChange } = props

    describe("<Input />", () => {

      describe("onChange", () => {
        test("function call", () => {
          const { getByTestId } = render(<Input {...props} />);
          const e = expect.objectContaining({ target: expect.objectContaining({ name, value: 'value here' })});

          fireEvent.change(getByTestId('input-name'), { target: { value: 'value here', name }});
```

this works

```
          expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

here is the error:

```
          expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(e);

Expected: ObjectContaining {"target": ObjectContaining {"name": "name", "value": "value here"}}
Received: {"_reactName": "onChange", "_targetInst": null, "bubbles": true, "cancelable": false, "currentTarget": null, "defaultPrevented": false, "eventPhase": 3, "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isTrusted": false, "nativeEvent": {"isTrusted": false}, 
"target": <input aria-invalid="false" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" data-testid="input-name" id="outlined-label" name="name" type="text" value="" />, "timeStamp": 1624028430742, "type": "change"}

        });
      });
    });
```

The value on input is empty.
I tried whit userEvent and still not working.
How can i test onChange to be called with the new value?
Thank you..

Comment: Rather than testing if the `onChange` callback is called properly, test if the `name` and `email` values get correctly updated on the UI.